# Compiling assests in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.4

[image]

While compiling assests in laravel using `npn run dev` I am getting the following error.

Comment: what error you see

Comment: @SidHeart, error is shown in attached image. and thank you for reply

Comment: i posted sollution for your question

Comment: Subhash, you should add the error as plain-text, not (only) as image. Also, you haven't marked **any** answer on **any** of your questions as accepted. Continuing to fail to do so will lead to a situation where people will refuse to help you. You should really go through your question history and sort that out soon.

Answer (score 0):

its happen in new version of npm just type

```
npm install express
```

than you can use `npm install`
if you getting this error again type again

```
npm install express
```

or you can use `npm run watch`

Comment: I updated my `node` and `npm` and it worked. Thank you for help

Comment: Subhash, if this answer solved your issue, you should mark it as *accepted* (tick mark on the left hand side) and optionally upvote it, too. This way, your question will be marked as solved.